# SQL Returning More Results When Optionals are commented out

Tags: sql, t-sql

got a bit of a situation here with sql, i am changing a piece of sql for a stored procedure, i have written what is below so far and i am now hitting a wall,

when i run the query AS is, it will return me 19 results, comment out everything that is showing as a optional module, and it returns 31 results,
The idea behind this is to basically read from a xml file, determine the values in the file and then match the values we have in this sql, so it will say if a is yes then 1, if b is no then 0,
So its a yes its licensed or no its not licensed scenario,

However i dont think its functioning as it should.

```
   -- Grab our license
 DECLARE @xml XML
 SELECT TOP 1 @xml = CAST(LicenceKey AS xml) FROM Organisation

 -- Calculate our licensed modules
 DECLARE @LicensedModules TABLE (moduleid INT)

 Declare @optionalmodules table (moduleid INT,description varchar (100))

 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (1,'R9')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (2,'S8')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (6,'S7')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (8,'A6')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (9,'C5')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (10,'S4')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (11,'A2')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (12,'P4')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (13,'PSL')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (14,'H4')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (15,'F2')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (16,'C1')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (17,'H2')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (18,'P3')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (20,'G1')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (21,'E2')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (22,'R1')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (23,'H1')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (24,'S2')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (25,'i1')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (26,'G1')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (27,'S1')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (28,'E1')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (29,'F1')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (31,'T2')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (32,'A1')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (33,'P2')
 INSERT INTO @optionalmodules (moduleid, description) values (16016,'P1')


INSERT INTO @LicensedModules

    SELECT CAST(sl.LookupReference AS INT)--,
        --sl.LookupReference, 
        --sl.Description, 
        --m.*,
        --cast(case license.value('.', 'varchar(3)') when 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end as bit) as optModLicenced,
        --case WHEN m.moduleid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE cast(case license.value('.', 'varchar(3)') when 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end as bit) END AS isLicenced
    FROM SystemLookup sl
        LEFT JOIN @optionalmodules m ON sl.LookupReference = m.moduleid 
        Left Join @xml.nodes('//Modules/*') as organisation(license) on m.description = organisation.license.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)')
    WHERE sl.LookupTypeId = 1 
        AND case WHEN m.moduleid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE cast(case license.value('.', 'varchar(3)') when 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end as bit) END = 1

Select * FROM @LicensedModules
```

Comment: Are you saying that you get different number of rows by commenting and un-commenting those line in the select clause?

Comment: @AmanB yes thats exactly it

Comment: I've noticed you're trying to cast sl.LookupReference as int in select. however, in join you're comparing it against moduleId without converting it? sl.LookupReference = m.moduleid

Comment: @AmanB Yes i see that, however im not sure why, this could lead to a possible change as lookupreference and module id are bot Integers anyway

Comment: I cannot follow that query.   m in the where turns that into an inner join.

Comment: Aside: Based on the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) `case WHEN m.moduleid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE cast(case license.value('.', 'varchar(3)') when 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end as bit) END = 1` will convert the cast `bit` back to an `int` to match the first return value (`1`) of the outer `case`. Cast that as a `bit` and the result of the outer `case` will be a `bit`, then converted to an `int` to compare `= 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like in the WHERE clause, if @optionalmodules is not present or not matched, then it will always include the row (m.moduleid IS NULL in the CASE statement).

If the @optionalmodules table has a value that matches sl.LookupReference, then it will only include items where the license is 'Yes', which may result in fewer rows being returned.